# using single thread for waiting on message queue and socket

Tags: linux, multithreading

I have 2 threads in one process. I am using message queue for inter thread communication and thread 2 and process 1 communicate using socket.

Thread 2 waiting on condition variable on message queue, once thread 1 write to message queue it set the condition variable thread 2 wake up and start processing.
Other process also post to socket on thread 2. 
My problem is how to poll on message queue and socket both in a single thread?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO a cleaner implementation is a thread listening on socket and putting all incoming requests in the message queue and one or more threads reading from message queue synchronously or asynchronously and processing the incoming messages. See Java NIO